# Map mv command to each row of file and directory names lists

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, scripting

I have two files of file and directory names. I want to map `mv` command from each row of a filenames file to each row in the directory names file. The files are small.

If it helps I have files named sequentially (say f1, f2, f3...f1000). Is there any way to do it in a loop reading one file and one directory?

There can be 3 use cases: One file to many directories, Many files to one directory and many files to many directories (1 file/line = 1 dir/line in my case). My use case pertains to the last one. I have seen `xargs` being used in some of the use cases but I am not sure how to modify for my use case.

Following questions do not help: [Moving large number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942422/moving-large-number-of-files)

Comment: One idea: use `mapfile` to load each file into an array. Iterate from 0 to N and use that as the index into the two arrays to get a pair of names to use with `mv`.

Comment: also asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/565763/4667

Comment: Something like `paste <(sed 's/^/mv /' files) dirs | bash`? Some adjustment required if any file or directory names have to be quoted. If you show some example input, answers can be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a file named **files** that contains file names, each in a new line, and a file named **dirs** with directories each in a new line, both having the same number of entries eg:

**files**

```
file1
file2
file3
```

**dirs**

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
```

Then to move file1 to dir1, file2 to dir2 and so on you can use the command:

```
paste dirs files | xargs -n2 mv -t
```

`paste` joins the lines from both files, then `xargs` takes two arguments and calls the `mv` command with them. The `-t` option selects the destination directory. Below is the relevant fragment from the `mv` documentation.

```
mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
          move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```